# PyTorch Autoencoder - artifacts during image reconstruction

Tags: python, image, pytorch, padding, autoencoder

I have a problem with implementation of an autoencoder in Pytorch. I have input images in grayscale of size 100x100 pixels. During reconstruction I have some artifacts on the right side and on the bottom of the reconstructed image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXzFA.png)

## The architecture of the autoencoder is as follows:

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 encoded_space_dim,
                 lin_dims):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder_cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 8, 3, stride=2, padding=1),    #1 image divided to 8 feature maps,                                                                 kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1),   #8 feature maps divided to 16, kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 2, stride=2, padding=0),  #16 feature maps divided to 32, kernel 2x2 and padding 0 in order to achieve image size 12x12 pixels
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, stride=2, padding=1),  #32 feature maps to 64, kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, stride=2, padding=1), #64 feature maps to 128, kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )

        self.flatten = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1)

        self.encoder_lin = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(128*3*3, lin_dims[0]),            #3x3(kernel size) x  number of feature maps in last layer so in this case 128
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(lin_dims[0], lin_dims[1]),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(lin_dims[1], encoded_space_dim)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder_cnn(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.encoder_lin(x)
        return x

class Decoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 encoded_space_dim,
                 lin_dims):
        super().__init__()

        self.decoder_lin = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(encoded_space_dim, lin_dims[0]),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(lin_dims[0], lin_dims[1]),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(lin_dims[1], 128*3*3),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )

        self.decoder_cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),   #128 maps to 64, kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),    #64 maps to 32, kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 2, stride=2, padding=0, output_padding=1),    #32 maps to 16, kernel 2x2
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 8, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),     #16 maps to 8, kernel 3x3
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)       #8 maps to 1, kernel 3x3
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.decoder_lin(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 128, 3, 3)       
        x = self.decoder_cnn(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

```
# print encoder summary
summary(encoder, (1, 100, 100))
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1            [-1, 8, 50, 50]              80
              ReLU-2            [-1, 8, 50, 50]               0
            Conv2d-3           [-1, 16, 25, 25]           1,168
              ReLU-4           [-1, 16, 25, 25]               0
            Conv2d-5           [-1, 32, 12, 12]           2,080
              ReLU-6           [-1, 32, 12, 12]               0
            Conv2d-7             [-1, 64, 6, 6]          18,496
              ReLU-8             [-1, 64, 6, 6]               0
            Conv2d-9            [-1, 128, 3, 3]          73,856
             ReLU-10            [-1, 128, 3, 3]               0
          Flatten-11                 [-1, 1152]               0
           Linear-12                 [-1, 1000]       1,153,000
             ReLU-13                 [-1, 1000]               0
           Linear-14                  [-1, 750]         750,750
             ReLU-15                  [-1, 750]               0
           Linear-16                  [-1, 500]         375,500
================================================================
Total params: 2,374,930
Trainable params: 2,374,930
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.04
...
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.62
Params size (MB): 9.06
Estimated Total Size (MB): 9.72
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
# print decoder summary
summary(decoder, (1, encoded_space_dim))
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Linear-1               [-1, 1, 750]         375,750
              ReLU-2               [-1, 1, 750]               0
            Linear-3              [-1, 1, 1000]         751,000
              ReLU-4              [-1, 1, 1000]               0
            Linear-5              [-1, 1, 1152]       1,153,152
              ReLU-6              [-1, 1, 1152]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-7             [-1, 64, 6, 6]          73,792
              ReLU-8             [-1, 64, 6, 6]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-9           [-1, 32, 12, 12]          18,464
             ReLU-10           [-1, 32, 12, 12]               0
  ConvTranspose2d-11           [-1, 16, 25, 25]           2,064
             ReLU-12           [-1, 16, 25, 25]               0
  ConvTranspose2d-13            [-1, 8, 50, 50]           1,160
             ReLU-14            [-1, 8, 50, 50]               0
  ConvTranspose2d-15          [-1, 1, 100, 100]              73
================================================================
Total params: 2,375,455
Trainable params: 2,375,455
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.00
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.68
Params size (MB): 9.06
Estimated Total Size (MB): 9.75
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
loss_fn = nn.L1Loss()
batch_size = 128

#latent space 
encoded_space_dim = 500
enc_dims = [1000, 750]
dec_dims = [750, 1000]

# Encoder & Decoder
encoder = Encoder(
    encoded_space_dim=encoded_space_dim,
    lin_dims=enc_dims
).to(device)

decoder = Decoder(
    encoded_space_dim=encoded_space_dim,
    lin_dims=dec_dims
).to(device)

# Optimizer
params_to_optimize = [
    {'params': encoder.parameters()},
    {'params': decoder.parameters()}
]
optim = torch.optim.Adam(params_to_optimize)
```

In order to calculate the architecture I used the following formula:
((n+2p-f)/s)+1, where:
n - image size, in my case 100 in the first layer
p - padding,
s - stride,
f - kernel size,
1 is bias.

To sum up, I think the architecture is ok, if I try to play for example with padding I receive an error of wrong dimensions. I cant see any other way to implement it. If this would be casused by oversampling the whole picture would be bad and not only two edges so I think oversampling is also not the problem. Any advices? I am running out of ideas.
Best regards

Comment: Rounding vs truncation often could produce artifacts in the last bin

Comment: Thanks! That gave me idea to make one layer size 14 instead of 12 so not to cut. Now it works! Sometimes one man can see immediately what someone else could not for a long time. Thank you my friend!